# How to replace missing characters in a string with a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to replace missing characters in a string with a dictionary. Take **t-a-19-/** for example. I want to replace the dashes with every possible letter or number from an array.

I tried using the replace() function, but it can't take arrays. How would I do the same function but with arrays?

Here's my code:

```
word = "t-a-19-/"

# Alpha numeric dictionary
alphanumericdict = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

# Replaces string with dictionary
brute = word.replace('-', alphanumericdict);
print(brute);
```

I get this error because the replace() function only takes strings, not lists.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bruteforce.py", line 17, in <module>
    brute = word.replace('-', alphanumericdict);
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not list
```

Comment: Your `alphanumericdict` is a list not a dictionary -- what are you trying to accomplish (what should `brute` be?)

Comment: What result are you expecting? Are you aware of the difference between dict and list?

Comment: alphanumericidct is a list btw..but are you saying you want to generate all options from taaa19a/ to tzaz19z/ ?

Comment: Dictionary includes a key-value pair within curly braces. Square brackets is a list.

Comment: I think you want something like `brute = [word.replace("-",i) for i in d]`.

Comment: yeah, I want to generate all options from taaa19a/ to tzaz19z/, how would i go about doing this? @DerekEden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
import itertools
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase #'abcdefg....'

for c1,c2,c3 in itertools.product(letters, repeat=3):
    print(word.replace('-','%s')%(c1,c2,c3))
```

output:

```
taaa19a/
taaa19b/
taaa19c/
taaa19d/
taaa19e/
.
.
.
tzaz19v/
tzaz19w/
tzaz19x/
tzaz19y/
tzaz19z/
```

Comment: Good answer. BTW, you don't have to make `letters` since `str` is already an iterable: `itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)` works just fine

Comment: you're right.. shouldve thought of that, thanks